# Shiny Dashboard - dynamic sidebar icon

Tags: icons, shiny, sidebar, dashboard

I am trying to change the sidebar icons dynamically according to the status of the current test I am running(could be "Live" or "Archived"). I have tried the below to assign the value of the icon to a reactive output, however I can't get it to work.

**ui.R**

```
  menuItem("AB calculator ", tabName = "calculator", icon = icon("hand-o-right")),
  menuItem("AB calculator ", tabName = "test1", icon = icon(uiOutput('iconTest')))
```

**server.R**

```
      output$iconTest<-renderUI({
      "th"
      })
```

Here is a reproducible example

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = bootstrapPage(

    dashboardHeader(
      title=" dashboard",
      titleWidth = 250

    ),

    dashboardSidebar(

     sidebarMenu(

        menuItem("AB calculator ", tabName = "test1", icon = icon(uiOutput('iconTest')))

      )
    ),

    dashboardBody(
    )

),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$iconTest<-renderUI({
        iconTest<-"th"
      })

    }
  )
```

Thanks

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can render the entire `menuItem`?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    dashboardHeader(title=" dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu( uiOutput('iconTest'))),
    dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$iconTest <- renderUI({
      menuItem("AB calculator ", tabName = "test1", icon = icon('th'))
    })
  }
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]