# How to dynamically render a button icon in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, icons

My current app has an `actionButton` dynamically rendered using `uiOutput` and `renderUI` such that its label changes depending upon what the user is up to. Here's a very dumb reprex:

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Have a button to press
  actionButton("test_button",
               uiOutput("button_label"),
               icon = icon("forward"))
)
# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  #Have a reactive value serving as a switch
  reactives1 <- reactiveValues(label_switch = 0)
  #Increment the switch upon every button press
  observeEvent(input$test_button, {
    reactives1$label_switch = reactives1$label_switch + 1
  })
  #Depending on whether the switch is odd or event, dynamically render the button label.
  observeEvent(reactives1$label_switch, {
    if(reactives1$label_switch %% 2 == 0) {
      output$button_label <- renderUI({ "I'm happy!" })
    } else {
      output$button_label <- renderUI({ "I'm sad!" })
    }
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Frustratingly, though, I can't seem to figure out how to do the exact same thing with the icon on the button. For example, this doesn't work:

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Have a button to press
  actionButton("test_button",
               "Press this button to change the icon!",
               uiOutput("button_icon"))
)
# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  #Have a reactive value serving as a switch
  reactives1 <- reactiveValues(icon_switch = 0)
  #Increment the switch upon every button press
  observeEvent(input$test_button, {
    reactives1$icon_switch = reactives1$icon_switch + 1
  })
  #Depending on whether the switch is odd or event, dynamically render the button icon.
  observeEvent(reactives1$icon_switch, {
    if(reactives1$icon_switch %% 2 == 0) {
    output$button_icon <- renderUI({ shiny::icon("arrow-left") })
    } else {
      output$button_icon <- renderUI({ shiny::icon("arrow-right") })
    }
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

R Shiny doesn't seem to be recognizing that `icon()` is being called; I get an error that I need to use `shiny::icon()` to render the icon even though that's what I'm doing. I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267390/shiny-dashboard-dynamic-sidebar-icon) that I may need to be rendering the entire button dynamically, but I'd prefer not to do that unless I have to. It also doesn't explain why I can pull this trick with the button label but not the button icon. I've seen elsewhere that the `renderUI()` call may be overriding the classes/form of my icon object, but it doesn't seem to matter where I call `icon()`; I get an error either way.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the icon in the label, with the help of the **fontawesome** package.

Do not use a `render` function inside an observer, this is not recommended.

```r
library(shiny)
library(fontawesome)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Have a button to press
  actionButton("test_button",
               uiOutput("button", inline = TRUE))
)
# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  #Have a reactive value serving as a switch
  reactives1 <- reactiveValues(icon_switch = 0)
  #Increment the switch upon every button press
  observeEvent(input$test_button, {
    reactives1$icon_switch = reactives1$icon_switch + 1
  })
  #Depending on whether the switch is odd or event, dynamically render the button icon.
  output$button <- renderUI({
    if(reactives1$icon_switch %% 2 == 0) {
    tags$span("Press the button", fa_i("arrow-left"))
    } else {
    tags$span("Press the button", fa_i("arrow-right"))
    }
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It sure works! Thanks! I'll admit I am currently using renderUI inside of observers all over the place haha! Why isn't this recommended? Should the renderUIs just always be based on reactives and then be set up to return nothing if the reactiveValues indicate a given UI should be "off" right now? I'd be curious to know more about best practices.